# how to get access token from oAuth2 token server in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, rest, oauth-2.0, jwt

I don't use VBA very often to create scripts, but this time I have to write a script which interacts with REST APIs that require `oAuth2` authentication and passing token as header in order to receive a successful response.

Appreciate if you can point me to helpful articles or examples that I can review? Ideally I want to convert below to Excel, VBA, and use user authorization code as my preferred choice of grant type.

I can achieve this in Python, but I am struggling to convert this to VBA

```
Token_url = <Token_url>
client_id = <client_id>
client_secret = <client_secret>
application_api_url = <application_api_url>
scope = <scope>

import requests

def get_access_token(url, client_id, client_secret):
    response = requests.post(
        url,
        data={"grant_type": "client_credentials","scope":scope},
        auth=(client_id, client_secret),
        verify=False
    )
    return response.json()["access_token"]
    
token = get_access_token(Token_url, client_id, client_secret)

api_call_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}

response = requests.request("GET", application_api_url , headers=api_call_headers)
```

I can write a vba that can receive a response from an open api, but I am not sure how to pass my authentication information - something similar to the definition I wrote in python - to successfully receive token and use it to interact with my application api.

Comment: Maybe look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70771374/api-oauth2-with-vba-error-missing-grant-type